# Having issue with a custom javascript slideshow element. Main button unresponsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow, squarespace

I'm having some trouble integrating a javascript slideshow into my squarespace website. Everything appears fine on the page but the button to view the slideshow gallery is unresponsive.

- Here is what I am trying to implement: [link](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/01/28/scattered-polaroids-gallery/)
- And the page on my website with the culprit: [website](https://www.samschrag.com/pagefd)

I'm not certain if the javascript or css files just aren't being linked properly? I'm injecting the scripts and css via header injection, site wide and on the individual page itself and even tried the footer. I attempted to host the files locally, but tried to do the src files from the actual source website too and neither worked.

Here is what I'm using in the site header:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://tympanus.net/Development/ScatteredPolaroidsGallery/js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<script src="//https://tympanus.net/Development/ScatteredPolaroidsGallery/js/photostack.js"></script>
<script src="//https://tympanus.net/Development/ScatteredPolaroidsGallery/js/classie.js" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://tympanus.net/Development/ScatteredPolaroidsGallery/css/component.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://tympanus.net/Development/ScatteredPolaroidsGallery/css/demo.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://tympanus.net/Development/ScatteredPolaroidsGallery/css/normalize.css"/>
```

And this is the code I'm using on the page itself:

```
<section id="photostack-1" class="photostack photostack-start">
                <div>
                    <figure style="transform: translate(200px, 200px) rotate(-16deg);">
                        <a href="img" class="photostack-img"><img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/529b047ce4b069bc9bedcff4/1589934385738-MXL1GUJ92IVZN0DEDXOL/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kPe5RiKppm9GG6ppTb_Faql7gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z5QHyNOqBUUEtDDsRWrJLTm0EJvx1ti9yXQ8tz8yvmwB9n_0euyg3xEuJeFkq2YFCnXL5lexUHVZRnE2OrpUbZC/astro?format=500w" alt="img04"></a>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2 class="photostack-title">Astro</h2>
                            <div class="photostack-back">
                                <p>Sci Fi- Short Film.</p>
                            </div>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <figure style="transform: translate(360px, 20px) rotate(-11deg);">
                        <a href="img11" class="photostack-img"><img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/529b047ce4b069bc9bedcff4/1589934475663-W46PFG3RJVBBJMTKP36O/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kPmLlvCIXgndBxNq9fzeZb1Zw-zPPgdn4jUwVcJE1ZvWQUxwkmyExglNqGp0IvTJZamWLI2zvYWH8K3-s_4yszcp2ryTI0HqTOaaUohrI8PIFMLRh9LbupWL4Bv1SDYZc4lRApws2Snwk0j_RSxbNHMKMshLAGzx4R3EDFOm1kBS/fragmenteddreams?format=500w" alt="img05"></a>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2 class="photostack-title">Fragmeented Dreamscapes</h2>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <figure data-shuffle-iteration="2" style="transform: translate(360px, 380px) rotate(24deg);">
                        <a href="img3" class="photostack-img"><img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/529b047ce4b069bc9bedcff4/1590138240444-N11DXMNU6PT1QWSR2XOL/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kBVDUY_ojHUJPbTAKvjNhBl7gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z5QHyNOqBUUEtDDsRWrJLTmmV5_8-bAHr7cY_ioNsJS_wbCc47fY_dUiPbsewqOAk2CqqlDyATm2OxkJ1_5B47U/AstroTeaser?format=500w" alt="img01"></a>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2 class="photostack-title">Astro Teaser</h2>
                            <div class="photostack-back">
                                <p>Teaser</p>
                            </div>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <figure style="transform: translate(200px, -160px) rotate(18deg);">
                        <a href="img99" class="photostack-img"><img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/529b047ce4b069bc9bedcff4/1591166215066-5Z5Z1ZLC4RXREUG7915N/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kPtRZ3OyglXDuVt0f2hKzkxZw-zPPgdn4jUwVcJE1ZvWQUxwkmyExglNqGp0IvTJZamWLI2zvYWH8K3-s_4yszcp2ryTI0HqTOaaUohrI8PIe9rtU8Gvg7TAs5vyBCaS2OgMHSRDLS_ROxGACNng4OMKMshLAGzx4R3EDFOm1kBS/votm?format=500w" alt="img02"></a>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2 class="photostack-title">VOTM: Happiness</h2>
                            <div class="photostack-back">
                                <p>Documentary</p>
                            </div>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <figure data-shuffle-iteration="3" style="transform: translate(40px, 20px) rotate(30deg);">
                        <a href="img293" class="photostack-img"><img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/529b047ce4b069bc9bedcff4/1590138931244-86ALDDADTARYJEZSBCHH/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kBVDUY_ojHUJPbTAKvjNhBl7gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z5QHyNOqBUUEtDDsRWrJLTmuRu0Pfuf5F0yH2Y0n9Wb2uSXfk79yzklavJJ48t78dp27rAT2psOBuL_FmvkUhyS/SomethingAboutLove?format=500w" alt="img03"></a>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2 class="photostack-title">Something About Love</h2>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <figure data-shuffle-iteration="2" style="transform: translate(-120px, 200px) rotate(-1deg);">
                        <a href="img1" class="photostack-img"><img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/529b047ce4b069bc9bedcff4/1590140420704-6U1QZXZD4EQG7HYERP1L/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kBd2ZI0C_2Vnzz7G8X3m5-0UqsxRUqqbr1mOJYKfIPR7LoDQ9mXPOjoJoqy81S2I8N_N4V1vUb5AoIIIbLZhVYxCRW4BPu10St3TBAUQYVKcl_UWDHYh_IdE-775gCeAieDvP1eLt0Tq8Wozg89XLEiCtQgz8i36nHhY7a_IcOjR/analogfantasy?format=500w" alt="img06"></a>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2 class="photostack-title">Analog Fantasy</h2>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <figure data-dummy="" style="transform: translate(360px, 200px) rotate(35deg);">
                        <a href="#" class="photostack-img"><img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/529b047ce4b069bc9bedcff4/1590146134911-LD2AAWY16Q980K51528H/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kCPjJEwVxoWu-a6fDO2tahlZw-zPPgdn4jUwVcJE1ZvWQUxwkmyExglNqGp0IvTJZUJFbgE-7XRK3dMEBRBhUpze_Z4sdv8hB8zEChgnI12DtbFgBqcamF6hCjCZbNhJg7A7Vo3M9FKy7w1-yY0so-A/snap?format=500w" alt="img07"></a>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2 class="photostack-title">Snap</h2>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <figure data-dummy="" style="transform: translate(40px, 200px) rotate(18deg);">
                        <a href="#" class="photostack-img"><img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/529b047ce4b069bc9bedcff4/1590141450252-108YRC6E9WJT8SRB10CM/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kKgZtcdlUes5P2L9YJKMNR9Zw-zPPgdn4jUwVcJE1ZvWQUxwkmyExglNqGp0IvTJZamWLI2zvYWH8K3-s_4yszcp2ryTI0HqTOaaUohrI8PI2do-h5XTUtMqWoz33tEUzyli8rEcalX0VCIynkzrz10KMshLAGzx4R3EDFOm1kBS/Spaces?format=500w" alt="img08"></a>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2 class="photostack-title">Spaces</h2>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <figure data-dummy="" style="transform: translate(-120px, 20px) rotate(-13deg);">
                        <a href="#" class="photostack-img"><img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/529b047ce4b069bc9bedcff4/1590141702876-ZAXMKQ5UL3D3DONFKGPP/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kBVDUY_ojHUJPbTAKvjNhBl7gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z5QHyNOqBUUEtDDsRWrJLTmmV5_8-bAHr7cY_ioNsJS_wbCc47fY_dUiPbsewqOAk2CqqlDyATm2OxkJ1_5B47U/Verve?format=500w" alt="img09"></a>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2 class="photostack-title">Verve</h2>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <figure data-dummy="" style="transform: translate(200px, 380px) rotate(24deg);">
                        <a href="#" class="photostack-img"><img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/529b047ce4b069bc9bedcff4/1590142848285-J4N79CPF2FJ1TTW6YZWM/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kBVDUY_ojHUJPbTAKvjNhBl7gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z5QHyNOqBUUEtDDsRWrJLTmmV5_8-bAHr7cY_ioNsJS_wbCc47fY_dUiPbsewqOAk2CqqlDyATm2OxkJ1_5B47U/2015?format=500w" alt="img10"></a>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2 class="photostack-title">2015</h2>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <figure data-dummy="" style="transform: translate(40px, -160px) rotate(-27deg);">
                        <a href="#" class="photostack-img"><img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/529b047ce4b069bc9bedcff4/1590143190384-MBEOYVNE8BD8QNFSB1YD/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kKyAC95JBJFAHkOhaWLMhegUqsxRUqqbr1mOJYKfIPR7LoDQ9mXPOjoJoqy81S2I8N_N4V1vUb5AoIIIbLZhVYxCRW4BPu10St3TBAUQYVKcMrw2Lzx3vZZ2SRyPKp_cy8Fa903fvwYgupJ5zY56wUUeUlUEtR9yBq459QlM-TTV/Retro?format=500w" alt="img11"></a>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2 class="photostack-title">Retro</h2>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <figure data-dummy="" style="transform: translate(360px, -160px) rotate(-16deg);">
                        <a href="#" class="photostack-img"><img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/529b047ce4b069bc9bedcff4/1590144058387-WIH5KKL2OCRLCB9FY2V8/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kKyAC95JBJFAHkOhaWLMhegUqsxRUqqbr1mOJYKfIPR7LoDQ9mXPOjoJoqy81S2I8N_N4V1vUb5AoIIIbLZhVYxCRW4BPu10St3TBAUQYVKcMrw2Lzx3vZZ2SRyPKp_cy8Fa903fvwYgupJ5zY56wUUeUlUEtR9yBq459QlM-TTV/kairos?format=500w" alt="img12"></a>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2 class="photostack-title">Kairos</h2>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <figure data-dummy="" style="transform: translate(200px, 200px) rotate(9deg);">
                        <a href="#" class="photostack-img"><img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/529b047ce4b069bc9bedcff4/1590145327146-COJS2MK0SHSO6F03K5XW/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kAEJrbsFhWLqsgpoQx73qC1Zw-zPPgdn4jUwVcJE1ZvWQUxwkmyExglNqGp0IvTJZUJFbgE-7XRK3dMEBRBhUpyf-i7HqzWRj6Qnixywj4DB-I0eAIFeuR6DviqjBRr8uBbu3jqDLNXNrXP7XxnmM3k/Aliment?format=500w" alt="img13"></a>
                        <figcaption>
                            <h2 class="photostack-title">Aliment</h2>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </div>
            <nav><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></nav></section>
```

Would love to know what I'm doing incorrectly and how I can learn to fix this. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the // from the start of the following lines:

```html
<script src="//https://tympanus.net/Development/ScatteredPolaroidsGallery/js/photostack.js"></script>
<script src="//https://tympanus.net/Development/ScatteredPolaroidsGallery/js/classie.js" ></script>
```

This is preventing those 2 files from being loaded.

Comment: Thank you for the note- I tried this edit, but I'm still encountering the unresponsive button/element.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like the site is blocking requests for the JS/CSS files so you'll need to load them locally.

You also need to add the following javascript just before the closing `</body>` tag.

```html
<script>
new Photostack( document.getElementById( 'photostack-1' ), {
  callback : function( item ) {
    //console.log(item)
  }
});         
</script>
```

I downloaded the project source code and pasted in your HTML from above and it works.